# fetch values from array within an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array, i wish to extract each value from this array.
The array is stored in $data.

```
{"success":true,"categories":
    [
        {"
            category_id":"C1",
            "parent_id":"P1",
            "name":"N1",
            "categories":
                [
                    {
                        "category_id":"C11",
                        "parent_id":"P11",
                        "name":"N11",
                    },
                    {
                        "category_id":"C12",
                        "parent_id":"P12",
                        "name":"N12",

                    },
                ],
            "status":"1"
        },

        {
            category_id":"C2",
            "parent_id":"P2",
            "name":"N2",
            "categories":
                [
                    {
                        "category_id":"C21",
                        "parent_id":"P21",
                        "name":"N21",
                            [
                                {
                                    "category_id":"C22",
                                    "parent_id":"P23",
                                    "name":"N24",
                                }
                            ],
                        "status":"2"
                    }
                ],
            "status":"3"
        },
    ]
}
```

I tried using

```
$total = $data['categories']['category_id'];
```

to fetch value `C11`

but wasn't able to do so.

can anyone tell how i can fetch all the data especially `C22`

Comment: json_decode and then loop it

Comment: @Feroz Akbar i don't know much about json, can u plz tell me how i can decode it

Comment: $total = $data['categories'][0]['category_id'];

Comment: every time you see a { it means an object and every [ means an array. So you were missing the array part [0]. To access each element you can use a recursive function that drills down to each element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$array = json_decode($data, true);
```

Then you can access the array as you have stated.
Or loop throught the categories:

```
if (!empty($array)) {
    foreach ($array['categories'] as $category) {
        echo $category['id'];
    }
}
```

You may have to do this recursively to loop through the categories within the categories. But it depends completely what you want to achieve. A nested loop could do the job if it is always just one level deep.

**EDIT**

The JSON you have provided is not quite right, I have given a corrected one below:

```
{
"success": true,
"categories": [
    {
        "category_id": "C1",
        "parent_id": "P1",
        "name": "N1",
        "categories": [
            {
                "category_id": "C11",
                "parent_id": "P11",
                "name": "N11"
            },
            {
                "category_id": "C12",
                "parent_id": "P12",
                "name": "N12"
            }
        ],
        "status": "1"
    },
    {
        "category_id": "C2",
        "parent_id": "P2",
        "name": "N2",
        "categories": [
            {
                "category_id": "C21",
                "parent_id": "P21",
                "name": "N21",
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "category_id": "C22",
                        "parent_id": "P23",
                        "name": "N24"
                    }
                ],
                "status": "2"
            }
        ],
        "status": "3"
    }
]
}
```

There were a few trailing commas and missing quote marks.

Comment: thanks i was able to convert it to array. but in the loop i got an error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). an u plz look into it

Comment: Your json is not valid, I have corrected it and added it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

The data is not in PHP array, its a JSON array. You have to decode it, by using json_decode() function.

Answer (score -1):

That's JSON, not php multidimensional array. You can use json_decode function to read through it.